# Windows application crashed out on "Out of memory"

Tags: memory-leaks, out-of-memory

The application I'm talking about is the VMWare vSphere 4.1 client.
My question is more common. If some application crashes on memory leak, is it necessarily problem in *this application process* (or in one initiated by) or it may be related to the another process not related to this specific application?

Comment: I'm disappointed that the VMware vSphere 5.0 client still leaks memory (a few hundred MBs per day) on Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

99.9% that the problem is in *this application process*.

As an alternative, you just don't have enough memory+swap space.

Try to enable swap file, if you have disabled it. Or increasing it's size.